# Why does my forEach() loop only execute once?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

I seem to have encountered a problem while looping through an array. The loop seems to only execute once, no matter the size of the array. I tried using different methods of looping and the error still persists.

As background information, I'm trying to make a bot with which users can award each other points. Everything else seemed alright. The only issue is that I wish to set up a maximum amount of points one user can give to another in a day, and I'm having problems looping through the array which stores this information.

These are the relevant parts of my code:

```
var timer = []; //Timer stores the values.

const getTimerSenderIdTable = (id) => { 
    let found = false;
    timer.forEach(function(dat) { // This is the problematic loop.
        if (dat.id === id) {
            found = dat;
        }
    })
    console.log("loop end, results: " + found);
    return found;
};

const timerManager = (senderId, targetId, pointSurp) => { //All arguments are integers.
    let d = new Date()
    if (getTimerSenderIdTable("date") !== d.getDate()) {
        timer = [];
        timer.push({"id":"date", "time":d.getDate()});
        if (getTimerSenderIdTable("date")) {
            if (getTimerSenderIdTable(senderId)) {
                console.log("path 1");
            } else {
                console.log("path 2");
                timer.push({"id":senderId, [targetId]:pointSurp});
            }
        }
    } else {
        if (getTimerSenderIdTable("date")) {
            if (getTimerSenderIdTable(senderId)) {
                console.log("path 3");
            } else {
                console.log("path 4");
                timer.push({"id":senderId, [targetId]:pointSurp});
            }
        }
    }
    console.log(timer)
};
```

*Edit:
Thank you for your comments. Here is an example:

Calling `timerManager(123456, 654321, 3)` will produce the following output:

```
loop end, results: false
loop end, results: [object Object]
loop end, results: false
path 2
[ { id: 'date', time: 28 }, { '654321': 3, id: 123456 } ]
```

(This is a repost from comments. My appologies.)

Comment: How are you calling this whole thing?

Comment: There's no way to know without knowing what's in the `timer` array at the time you call `getTimerSenderIdTable`. Unrelated, but `timerManager` is a bit difficult to reason about.

Comment: Does `timer` actually have multiple elements? Please create a [mre] that we can try ourselves. We need to see how many times `timerManager()` is being called and with what arguments.

Comment: Please provide a minimal, reproducible example (With example data and expected output).

Comment: You have some `console.log` statements: so, what is logged? And BTW, seems as if you needed `Array.prototype.find`, not `Array.prototype.forEach`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Here is an example:

Calling timerManager(123456, 654321, 3) will produce the following output:

loop end, results: false (line 1)
loop end, results: [object Object] (line two)
loop end, results: false (line three)
path 2 (line four)
[ { id: 'date', time: 28 }, { '654321': 3, id: 123456 } ] (line six and end of output)

Comment: I appologise for the spacing in my previous comment. As I mentioned, I am new here. I didn't know it would be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as @mbojko has pointed out, you'll want to use the [find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method for returning the found obj inside `getTimerSenderIdTable` function, like this

```
const getTimerSenderIdTable = (id) => { 
    return timer.find(item => item.id === id}); 
};
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. This seems to have worked. I'd also like to thank mbojko for his original comment. I have spent about 3 hours on this. You people are lifesavers.

Answer (score 1):

It seems because of this line

```
if (getTimerSenderIdTable("date") !== d.getDate()) {
        timer = [];
```

This will empty the array and next lines of code will only push single element

Comment: Thank you for your answer.

Unfortunately, this did not appear to solve the problem. There is also one thing I should've mentioned. I wish to store the array as JSON when I'm finished debugging, and as the values of the array ought to reset every day, I believe that line of code might be necessary. When the program is finished, this particular section of code should run only when the date changes, thus the array will reset every day.